# Why is a standard foreach loop faster?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I did a test and was really bummed to find that a standard `foreach` loop performed significantly faster than using array methods.

Using `foreach`:

```
$std_dev = 0;
$mean = self::calc_stat_mean($array);

$start = microtime(true);

foreach ($array as $value)
{

    $std_dev += pow(($value - $mean), 2);

}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Using array methods:

```
$mean = self::calc_stat_mean($array);

$start = microtime(true);

$std_dev = array_sum(array_map(function($value) use ($mean) {

    return pow(($value - $mean), 2);

}, $array));

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Can someone tell me why this is? I feel the latter method just seems better written and cleaner than the former but the hit in speed isn't worth it.

Comment: What is the difference in speed?

Comment: You will always have an overhead when calling many functions.

Comment: PHP has *always* been slow when calling functions. `array_map`, `array_walk`, `usort` etc., all suffer under this.

Comment: Standard `foreach` in your example contains a addition and a call to pow(); using array methods calls and array_sum(), array_map() with a closure.... not exactly the same

Comment: If you really want to do a decent array functions test to get your standard deviation, at least use `array_reduce()`... `$std_dev = array_reduce( $array, function($stdDev, $value) use ($mean) {
 return $stdDev += pow(($value - $mean), 2);
}, 0));`

Comment: And if speed really is so important: `$stdDev += ($value - $mean) * ($value - $mean)` is faster than `$std_dev += pow(($value - $mean), 2);` because it eliminates the function call overhead.... more than twice as fast in your original foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is so small that it isn't even worth worrying about.

Just pick something that matches your programming style, that you like better personally, and that will work better for your app.

Find other places to optimize... Don't stress over for, for each, and while!